# Data is not saved in TextArea. Probably due to page refresh

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs

I have code that works as I need. (If you select items in Select, then click Button. Selected value from Select should be copied and TextArea will be added and the cursor should be placed on the next line).
https://codesandbox.io/s/lingering-currying-mdksx

But when I transfer the module to another file. And now, when you click on the button, the entire page begins to refresh, and TextArea turns out to be empty. I think this is due to setState. How to save data in TextArea? I think need to get rid of page refresh. Bbut I dont know how.

Same code with the distant module
https://codesandbox.io/s/priceless-jennings-jkgef

P.S.
I don't know why, the ListBox file doesn't load in codesandbox, but everything works for me.

Comment: Try to set state in componentdidmount function in react life cycle when the page is reloading with the data received after selecting text from list

Comment: [Updated Second CodeSandBox URL](https://codesandbox.io/s/priceless-jennings-jkgef)

At this above url I have updated your code and now ListBox component is also loading successfully

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Its not a magic. Just change < form > to < div >**

I don’t know how, but I drank coffee, returned for a PC and everything worked on my main project.

[image]